Can I see how package configurations (CentOS/Ubuntu) are made for prebuilt packages?
We're facing long login times with sssd + ssh since we changed our default Linux to Ubuntu 2x.04 LTS Server. The configuration files are identical. With CentOS 8.5 it takes 1-4 seconds. With Ubuntu it takes either 6, 20 or > 50 seconds (depending on caches). With huge config tweaks we can reduce them to 12s. The server systems itself are configured the same, except the os.
Is it possible that CentOS build their SSSD package differently than Ubuntu?
How can I figure out how they were built?
Best regards.

Download the source packages (CentOS is out of support) and compare the build instructions (and sources itself)

"Is it possible that CentOS build their SSSD package differently than Ubuntu?"  Almost certainly they do. Ad @RomeoNinov said: compare the source packages which will show you what (custom) patches and tuning each distribution applies when building their binaries.
